# Error: no parsers registered for: "]a(r)" after upgrading to Gulp v4

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

So after doing a clean install on my Mac recently (so I guess it's possible that it's not just Gulp 4 which is causing the problem), I'm now having trouble with my Gulp tasks.

I've encountered a few errors along the way and have been able to fix some of them, but I'm stuck on this one. This is the full error:

```
Error: no parsers registered for: "]a(r)"
at parse (/node_modules/snapdragon/lib/parser.js:473:15)
at Parser.parse (/node_modules/snapdragon/lib/parser.js:477:24)
at Snapdragon.parse (/node_modules/snapdragon/index.js:122:28)
at Snapdragon.<anonymous> (/node_modules/braces/lib/braces.js:40:45)
at Braces.parse (/node_modules/braces/lib/braces.js:66:26)
at Braces.expand (/node_modules/braces/lib/braces.js:87:18)
at create (/node_modules/braces/index.js:142:15)
at memoize (/node_modules/braces/index.js:298:13)
at Function.braces.create (/node_modules/braces/index.js:165:10)
at Function.braces.expand (/node_modules/braces/index.js:81:17)
```

Googling the error seemed to suggest it might be related to `browser-sync` which I'm not using. But I've commented out any references to `live-reload` in case it was somehow related to that, bt still get the same error.

Along the way in trying to fix various issues, I've run the following:

```
$ npm install --global gulp-cli
$ npm rm gulp
$ npm install gulp
$ npm rebuild node-sass
$ npm outdated
$ npm install -g npm-check-updates
$ ncu -u
$ npm update
$ npm install
```

**Versions**

- Gulp CLI 2.2.0
- Gulp Local 4.0.2
- Node 13.7.0
- npm/npx 6.13.7

**Gulpfile.js**

```
"use strict";

// package vars
const pkg = require("./package.json");

// gulp
const gulp = require("gulp");

// load all plugins in "devDependencies" into the variable $
const $ = require("gulp-load-plugins")({
    pattern: ["*"],
    scope: ["devDependencies"]
});

// scss - build the scss to the build folder, including the required paths, and writing out a sourcemap
gulp.task("scss", () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Compiling scss");
    return gulp.src(pkg.paths.src.scss + '*.scss')
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe($.sass({
                includePaths: pkg.paths.scss
            })
            .on("error", $.sass.logError))
        .pipe($.cached("sass_compile"))
        .pipe($.autoprefixer())
        .pipe($.size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.build.css));
});

// tailwind task - build the Tailwind CSS
gulp.task("tailwind", () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Compiling tailwind css");
    return gulp.src(pkg.paths.build.css + '**/*.css')
        .pipe($.postcss([
            $.tailwindcss(pkg.paths.tailwindcss.conf),
            require("autoprefixer"),
        ]))
        .pipe($.if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            $.purgecss({
                extractors: [{
                    extractor: TailwindExtractor,
                    extensions: ["twig", "scss", "css", "js"]
                }],
                whitelist: pkg.globs.purgecssWhitelist,
                content: pkg.globs.purgecss
            })
        ))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.build.css));
});

// Custom PurgeCSS extractor for Tailwind that allows special characters in
// class names.
//
// https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss#extractor
class TailwindExtractor {
    static extract(content) {
        return content.match(/[A-z0-9-:\/]+/g);
    }
}

// css task - combine & minimize any distribution CSS into the public css folder, and add our banner to it
gulp.task("css", gulp.series("tailwind", "scss"), () => {
    $.fancyLog("-> Building css");
    return gulp.src(pkg.paths.build.css + '**/*.css')
        .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
        .pipe($.newer({dest: pkg.paths.dist.css}))
        .pipe($.print())
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
        .pipe($.if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
            $.cssnano({
                discardComments: {
                    removeAll: true
                },
                discardDuplicates: true,
                discardEmpty: true,
                minifyFontValues: true,
                minifySelectors: true
            })
        ))
        .pipe($.header(banner, {pkg: pkg}))
        .pipe($.sourcemaps.write("./"))
        .pipe($.size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(pkg.paths.dist.css))
        .pipe($.filter("**/*.css"))
        //.pipe($.livereload());
});

// set the node environment to development
gulp.task("set-dev-node-env", async function() {
    $.fancyLog("-> Setting NODE_ENV to development");
    return process.env.NODE_ENV = "development";
});

// Default task
gulp.task("default", () => {
    gulp.series("set-dev-node-env");
    // $.fancyLog("-> Livereload listening for changes");
    // $.livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch(pkg.paths.src.scss + "**/*.scss", gulp.series("css"));
    gulp.watch(pkg.paths.src.css + "**/*.css", gulp.series("css"));
    gulp.watch(pkg.paths.templates + "**/*.{twig}", () => {
        gulp.src(pkg.paths.templates)
            .pipe($.plumber({errorHandler: onError}))
            // .pipe($.livereload());
    });
    return
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Still not 100% sure what caused it.

It was from a Watch task looking at files in our Twig version of Pattern Lab.  It found some JS and SCSS files in there that were causing it break.  My guess would be an oddly formatted file name.

Comment: I moved on to Laravel Mix with webpack when this happened so I never got to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar mistake. The problem turned out to be that my root folder where all the projects were stored contained the characters "[" and "]". After renaming, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

To identify which file and who is responsible for this error, go to the file `node_modules\snapdragon\lib\parser.js`.

Replace this line:

```
throw new Error('no parsers registered for: "' + self.input.slice(0, 5) + '"');
```

With this one:

```
throw new Error('no parsers registered for: "' + self.input.slice(0, 5) + '" origin : ' + self.orig);
```

It will indicate the responsible file that you can ignore if needed.